# MSVCR110D.dll missing

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio 2013 for an opencv c++ project which I am just starting.With a very basic file the project compiles fine but when I run it, it first gave **MSVCR120D.dll** missing, I understand this is because of redistribute package, when I installed redistribute package of visual c++ 2013 the error changed to **MSVCR110D.dll** missing. I even went on to install the redistribute package 2012 but still get the same error.

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: The D suffix means your application is looking for the [debug versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851522/release-application-looking-for-msvcr110d-dll). Redistributable packages may not include those versions ?

Comment: If you're getting an error that MSVCR120D.dll is missing on the same machine you're building on, there's a serious problem with your Visual Studio installation.